# PayPal payments made to sandbox account instead of live account

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

We had a page set up to receive PayPal payments - it was still on testing/development, so we used a sandbox business account to receive payments.

Unfortunately, some users gained access to the page and successfully made payments. I logged into sandbox and found out that it successfully received the payments from non-sandbox accounts of real users.

I thought this would not be possible. So I tried it for myself - made a payment using my real PayPal account, and I was right - it did not work.

My question is: How was it possible that they were able to pay using their real account, but I couldn't? Second, since they paid to a sandbox account, was actual money deducted from their account? If yes, would refunding it from inside our sandbox business account work?

Comment: I think you better contact Paypal about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think anybody could have completed the transaction using a "real" account is if they paid using a credit card through a Payments Pro integration.  Are you using Payments Pro?

Any money paid to a sandbox account is fake, and no money would actually be transferred.

Comment: Which implies the OP has no commercial obligation to those customers.

Comment: I'm not using Payments Pro. I contacted PayPal and they could not explain how it happened. But I confirmed with the customers that they were indeed not charged for the transactions.